# ENOTFOUND Error on UDP socket with node.js 0.10

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to run some js with node 0.10 using UDP and I get errors. The API changes talks about the new all asynchronous dgram system but I can't run the example.

When I try :

```
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

s.bind(1234, function() {
    s.addMembership('224.0.0.114');
});
```

I get this :

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

I don't have any problems with node 0.8 .
I'm on windows 8 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try like this :

```
s.bind(1234,'0.0.0.0', function() {
  s.addMembership('224.0.0.114');
});
```

Does it give some error

Comment: Thanks ! No error now. I will try to run my full program but I think you perfectly resolve my problem :)